# Does it make sense to talk about a factor group by a non-subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

In a problem I've just completed, I show that we have the isomorphism $SL(2,\mathbb{C})/\{-I,I\} \cong \mathcal{M}$ where $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the group of 2x2 complex unimodular matrices, $\{-I,I \}$ are the identity and minus the identity matrices in that group, and $\mathcal{M}$ is the set of Mobius transformations of the complex plane. The author goes on to say that $SL(2,\mathbb{C})/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathcal{M}$.

My question is, does it even make sense to talk about $SL(2,\mathbb{C})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ when $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not strictly speaking a (normal) subgroup (or even subset) of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$? Or is this just a manner of speaking since clearly $\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \{-I,I\}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes to your last question. This is a common (slight) abuse. For example we may say $\mathbb{Z}_4 / \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, even though $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (the set of congruence classes mod $2$) is not literally a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (the set of congurence classes mod $4$).

Occasionally (but not too often in practice) this can lead to ambiguity. For example, what is $(\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) / \mathbb{Z}_2$? Well, it depends on what isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ we're talking about. The answer could be $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or it could be $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Context is key in these situations.

For $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ there is no ambiguity because there is only one normal subgroup of order $2$ (indeed there is only one element of order $2$).

Comment: Thank you! In your last sentence (fourth last word), did you mean "subgroup"?

Comment: No I literally meant element, which you can see by considering eigenvalues. But it's easier to see that there is only one normal subgroup of order $2$, because the nontrivial element would have to be central.

Comment: Ah I see, you were using order in the sense of the order of the subgroup generated by a given element. Thanks again!